Error: Undefined reference to '__imp__ZN18QgsUserInputWidgetC1EP7QWidget' in QGIS Qt6 project
For the past 4 days I am stuck here with this error, can't find help on google search:
C:\Users\D Besta\Documents\sample_qgis_pro\mainwindow.cpp:13: error: undefined reference to '__imp__ZN18QgsUserInputWidgetC1EP7QWidget'

Here are my files:
.pro file
    QT       += core gui xml
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++17

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

INCLUDEPATH += C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-qt6-dev/include C:/OSGeo4W/include #C:\OSGeo4W\QGIS\src\app C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Qt6\include #C:\OSGeo4W\QGIS\src\core C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-dev\include

#LIBS += "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-rel-dev\lib" -lqgis_core -lqgis_gui #C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-qt6-dev\lib\qgis_gui.lib C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-qt6-dev\lib\qgis_core.lib
LIBS += C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-qt6-dev/lib/qgis_3d.lib \
        C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-qt6-dev/lib/qgis_analysis.lib \
        C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-qt6-dev/lib/qgis_app.lib \
        C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-qt6-dev/lib/qgis_native.lib \
        C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-qt6-dev/lib/qgis_server.lib
# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

.h File
    #ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <qgsuserinputwidget.h>
#include <QWidget>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QWidget *tested=nullptr;
    QgsUserInputWidget *testwidget=nullptr;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H

mainwindow.cpp File
    #include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setGeometry(0, 0, 200, 200);
    setMinimumSize(200, 200);
    setWindowTitle("Integrated_Ground_Control_Station");

    testwidget = new QgsUserInputWidget(this);
    testwidget->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0,0,0)");
    testwidget->show();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
    delete testwidget;
}

